# Flutter How to display matrix correctly with shadows

Tags: flutter, matrix, dart, shadow

So basically I made a Widget that gets this `final List<List<Map>> _timetable;`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'lesson.dart';

class Timetable extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<Map>> _timetable;
  Timetable(this._timetable);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Timetable"),
        ),
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            for (var lessons in _timetable)
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (var info in lessons)
                    lesson(info)
                ],
              )
          ],
        )
      );
  }
}
```

lesson.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class lesson extends StatelessWidget {
  Map info = Map();
  lesson(this.info);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 1.0,
                  color: info.containsKey("color")
                      ? info["color"]
                      : Colors.purple[900],
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: info.containsKey("color")
                        ? info["color"]
                        : Colors.purple[900],
                    blurRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01, // has the effect of softening the shadow
                    spreadRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.005, // has the effect of extending the shadow
                    offset: Offset(
                      0.0, // horizontal, move right 10
                      0.0, // vertical, move down 10
                    ),
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(info["lesson"]),
                      Text(info["teacher"])
                    ],
                  ))),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and main.dart because it's where I call Timetable with the data:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:schoolify/screens/timetable/timetable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

List<List<Map>> days = List<List<Map>>();
List<Map> monday = List<Map>();
List<Map> tuesday = List<Map>();
List<Map> wednesday = List<Map>();
List<Map> thursday = List<Map>();
List<Map> friday = List<Map>();
List<Map> saturday = List<Map>();
List<Map> sunday = List<Map>();
Map german = Map();
Map english = Map();
Map mathematics = Map();
Map free = Map();


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    german["teacher"] = "Hr. DE";
    german["lesson"] = "DE";
    german["color"] = Colors.blue;
    english["teacher"] = "Mr. EN";
    english["lesson"] = "EN";
    english["color"] = Colors.pinkAccent;
    mathematics["teacher"] = "Fr. MA";
    mathematics["lesson"] = "MA";
    mathematics["color"] = Colors.green[700];
    free["teacher"] = "no one";
    free["lesson"] = "none";
    free["color"] = Colors.redAccent;

    monday.add(english);
    monday.add(german);
    monday.add(english);
    monday.add(german);
    monday.add(mathematics);

    tuesday.add(german);
    tuesday.add(german);
    tuesday.add(german);
    tuesday.add(german);
    tuesday.add(german);

    wednesday.add(english);
    wednesday.add(german);
    wednesday.add(english);
    wednesday.add(german);
    wednesday.add(mathematics);

    thursday.add(english);
    thursday.add(german);
    thursday.add(english);
    thursday.add(german);
    thursday.add(mathematics);

    friday.add(english);
    friday.add(german);
    friday.add(english);
    friday.add(german);
    friday.add(mathematics);

    saturday.add(english);
    saturday.add(german);
    saturday.add(english);
    saturday.add(german);
    saturday.add(mathematics);

    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);
    sunday.add(free);

    days.add(monday);
    days.add(tuesday);
    days.add(wednesday);
    days.add(thursday);
    days.add(friday);
    days.add(saturday);
    days.add(sunday);

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Timetable(days),
    theme: ThemeData(),

    );
  }
}
```

but the outcome is:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hflvi.jpg)

so please help me and make the shadow only to be on the ouside of lesson
PS
I am new to flutter, so sorry for this dumb question but I could not have figured it out by myself.

Comment: can you please share structure of your data ?

Comment: sorry what do you mean with structur of data? Did you mean to ask for an example List?